# Union times in sql oracle - difficult problem

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a big table with start times and end times.
It looks like this:
Start_time date-time (format: dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss),
End_time date-time (format: dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss)
**I might have rows that represent time which is included in other rows**

My desiarable result is a table that can solve this containing. I want take any firsy time and see next to him the last end time.

I tried to left join the table  with itself on start time between start time and end time if the end of the second is greater than the ending of the first. Then to do a sliding window and take the max end time with sliding window or even with group by.

However, this idea does take in account then I may have, for example:

```
10:05-10:10
10:07-10:12
10:09-10:15
10:11-10:20
```

So when I am joined I allegedly get 10:05-10:15 and 10:11-10:20. The row of 10:11 is not joined to the first row because it is not included in that time.
I have here again the same problem I had in the begining.

My desiarable result is actually for the rows above:
10:05-10:20
Seem to be a difficult problem.

I dont know plsql but thought maybe about doing some function that repeat this query until it has nothing to join?

Hope to get ypur help!
Thanks.

Comment: Please add the expected result. Also, what data type is that column?

Comment: PLease show a [mcve]

Comment: My type of data is date-time. The expected result is actually 10:05-10:20

Comment: Please include at least the structure of the table you are querying.

Comment: Added table structure

Comment: What you probably want is to aggregate rows with overlapping (and consecutive) time ranges. The time range itself should be merged. See https://community.oracle.com/thread/3731274#thread-message-13110149 as an example how to solve it.

Comment: Thanks kodo. Think that I was so searching for. I will try it and will update

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to format, but you can copy paste in your editor and than format.
Insted of my test data with operator "with" you may use your table.

I suppose you have some sort of ID so i include it:

```
with test_table as (
  select 1 id, to_date('2019-04-07 10:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-07 10:08', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual union all
  select 2 id, to_date('2019-04-07 10:07', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-07 10:10', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual union all
  select 3 id, to_date('2019-04-07 10:11', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-07 10:15', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual union all
  select 4 id, to_date('2019-04-07 10:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-07 10:20', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual union all

  select 5 id, to_date('2019-04-08 10:05', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-08 10:10', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual union all
  select 6 id, to_date('2019-04-08 10:07', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-08 10:12', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual union all
  select 7 id, to_date('2019-04-08 10:09', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-08 10:15', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual union all
  select 8 id, to_date('2019-04-08 10:11', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time, to_date('2019-04-08 10:20', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time from dual
)
select id, to_char(start_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') start_time,  to_char(end_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') end_time,
       (SELECT MAX(to_char(end_time, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi'))
        from test_table t2
        connect by nocycle
          prior t2.id != t2.id            and
          PRIOR end_time > start_time     and 
          PRIOR start_time < end_time
          start with t2.id = t1.id) max_date
from test_table t1;
```

Comment: try indenting each line of code by 4 spaces in the markdown editor

Comment: Ok, Thanx, I will try with markdown editor. I am new here, but i will learn :)